# Persistence configuration for CloudBees JavaEE/Glassfish application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish, persistence, cloudbees

I have a Java EE 7/Glassfish 4 application. How to configure JDBC Connection Pool and JDBC Resource in CloudBees?

The second question is, could I deploy an EAR file in CloudBees? How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create your database and bind it to your application in this way:

```
bees app:bind -a <account>/<appName> -db mydb
```

This is the equivalent of adding the jdbc resource and a jndi datasource will be created in your Glassfish4 container (have a look to the [Glassfish4 Cloudbees documentation](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Glassfish4) to know the valid jndi names)

If you want to create a connection pool,  you would just need to add additional parameters in your command:

i.e:

```
bees app:bind -a APP_ID -db DB_ID -as DATASOURCE_NAME maxActive=5 maxIdle=2 \
maxWait=10000 removeAbandoned=true removeAbandonedTimeout=60 logAbandoned=true \
validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow=true
```

Please refer to [this documentation](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DatabaseGuide) for additional information.

As far as I know, only the JBoss stacks support deployment of EAR files.